# OCMock setup for iOS with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, unit-testing, cocoa, xctest, ocmock

Trying to set up OCMock in iOS using CocoaPods, have a problem that persists in a new (trivial) project. This is in Xcode 8 but I suspect the problem is the setup rather than the use of CocoaPods.

I have the error:
 implicit declaration of function ‘OCMClassMock’ is invalid in C99

In my Podfile I have the following: pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.2'

I then followed the ocmock iOS Project setup as best I could and did the following:

- added the library to the test target set linker flags
- added #import  to my test .m file
- Added Header Search Paths as $(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/OCMock
- Set always Search User Paths to yes

`#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>
    @interface FinanceCalcWithTestsTests : XCTestCase
    @end
    - (void)testMasterViewControllerDeletesItemsFromTableView
     {
        id tableViewMock = OCMClassMock([UITableView class]);
     }`

Comment: This sounds like you're not importing the header file. I guess (because you didn't post your code) that the first use of OCMock is the attempt to create a mock object with `OCMClassMock`. If the compiler hasn't seen the header file, then it hasn't seen the definition of `OCMClassMock` and because it's followed by round brackets assumes it must be a call to a function.

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg I've added the code above - and I have imported the header file I believe....like I said it is trivial code.

Comment: What happens when you hold down the command key and then click on `OCMClassMock` in the code above? Where does Xcode take you?

Comment: Hi - it doesn't take me anywhere (question mark appears) however the link to the header file (predictably) takes me to the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just noticed what could be the solution: you are telling CocoaPods to get OCMock 2.2, but you are trying to use a feature that was only introduced in OCMock 3.0...